# How to make the septic tank safe for human entry

Tags: plumbing, safety, septic

My septic tank is hard sealed with concrete slab.

My mason and plumber wants to install two Effluent filter inside the septic tank.

So I'll call up the septic tank trucks ,they will suck the septic tank water using their truck.

I'm worried about the health and safety of my masons and plumber.

Here the workers don't indulge in entering this tank with oxygen cylinder like that.

so I'm thinking after septic water is emptied out.. I think I will fill the septic tank with fresh water and mix some disinfectant so all the toxic gases such as methane would've got dissolved or displaced by the new water body from the tank, when I drain this water out using the same truck it'll be in better condition .. i mean out of any toxic gases and I don't have to worry about the Mason or plumbers health and safety.

Is this a better approach if plumber and mason says no to oxygen cylinders.

Comment: I would think at least a blower/fan and medium sized hose  to blow fresh air into the tank would be needed.

Comment: Why are you opposed to the workers using oxgentanks ?  Doesn't the plumber know what the process is when doing the work he said is needed?

Comment: @RMDman - I'm not opposed actually, I motivate them to follow international safety standards ,but  it's the habit and nobody is using that around. Hence they feel it's too much for a simple task and nobody wants to do this

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - Makes sense hope this will blow all the toxic gases away if run continously but bit worried about complaints that I might receive from neighbors for bad odour

Comment: I don't know that it will blow out all the noxious gases, but it is all a parts per million kind of thing. If there is sufficient air going in, it should dilute anything harmful. Might be a good idea to start ventilating it an hour or two before anyone goes in. As far as neighbors, let them know there will be work being done and apologize in advance if there is any smell or noise from the work.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - Seems like a good idea. But is there any test kit or something which can find the presence of toxic gases in the septic chamber ? I just want to be sure before letting anyone in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please call septic tank specialists and speak to them. Do not do **anything** before speaking to them. A mason and plumber are not experienced enough to enter a septic tank, even one you have cleaned out. Leave whatever you want to do to septic professionals. And tell them what you want to do. They may be able help you, save you money, and do it safely.

Comment: Yeah, seconding this -- a septic tank is very much a hazardous (under OSHA rules, it'd require a permit to enter) confined space, and needs to be treated with the gravity such a thing warrants.

Comment: Problem is septic tank specialists in the local are are not keeping up to the laid out rules and regulation , they just do their own way. I even inquired one contractor but he says it's nothing to worry even septic related deaths are not rare.But I want to be bit careful from my side anyways.

Comment: Then call someone else that respects the OSHA rules. If someone dies in there, you're going to jail.

Comment: Contact your local building department, plumbing division and ask them to come to your home. explain to them what you are planning to do, and they will tell you 1) if what you propose to do is correct based on state and local regulations, and 2) if you need a permit to create a record to show it was done legally, and in the end inspected for legal completeness., and signed off. A permit protects you somewhat if something should happen. Also, If the plumber and brick layer are legit, have them make you an "additional insured" on their company liability insurance. If they can't, don't use them.

Comment: Yes you are right , Thanks